# QCD methods - Dirac trace, trace in color space, trace in flavor space

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, research-level, quarks, greens-functions, elementary-particles

What is meant by the following terms in QCD -
Dirac trace, trace in color space, trace in flavor space, etc. Could someone explain with an example (For eg. what's the diffrerence between something like $tr [A]$ and $tr_{Dirac} tr_{flavor} tr_{color} [A]$)?

Comment: How do you take the trace of $D\otimes F \otimes C$?

Comment: @Cosmas I understand it’s a tensor product of 3 vector spaces but I don’t get your question.

Comment: The trace of a tensor product is the product of traces of the tensor factors.

Comment: @Cosmas okay. Could you perhaps share any resource/link/chapter in a book where I can find this in a pedagogical manner, preferably with solved examples. I'm a self-taught in Field theory and hence have gaps in my familiarity with such techniques. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have resources. Wikipedia might help with the tensor product. What you ***must*** do yourself, if you have not already done it, is write down explicitly the 4x4 matrix $A\otimes B$ for 2x2 matrices *A* and *B* and understand the statement on traces. Its veracity should then be obvious. Nothing traceable to physics or QFT.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Tensor_product_of_linear_maps) is the sort of example I recommended. Take its trace.